# Which user executes the post-receive hook on a Windows machine?

Tags: git, windows-7, githooks

So I have that `post-receive` hook in my bare repo that shall update tickets in my trac installation (hook taken from http://trac.edgewall.org/attachment/wiki/TracGit/post-receive-hook.py).

The git repo is located on drive `G:` while the trac database is stored on `F:\user\trac\myproject`. I customized the original hook so that the paths are correct:

```
TRAC_ENV = 'F:\\User\\Trac\\myproject'
GIT_PATH = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\git.exe"
```

Before I uploaded the hook to my server, I verified the correct syntax (backslashes and so on) on my local machine where everything works fine.

Now, I uploaded the hook to `G:\git\myproject.git\hooks\post-receive` and I push some refs. But this gives me an error message:

```
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "hooks/post-receive", line 190, in <module>
remote:     env = open_environment(TRAC_ENV)
remote:   File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\trac\env.py", line 846, in open_environment
remote:   File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\trac\core.py", line 124, in __call__
remote:   File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\trac\env.py", line 283, in __init__
remote:   File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\trac\env.py", line 392, in verify
remote: trac.core.TracError: No Trac environment found at f:\user\trac\myproject
remote: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'f:\\user\\trac\\myproject\\VERSION'
```

So I guess it's an access rights related problem and the user that executes the `post-receive` hook has no access to the trac directory.

In order to overcome this: **which user do I need to give access to the trac database so that the hook gets executed successfully?**

Comment: Just passing by. Is it correct that you have single quote in TRAC_ENV?

Comment: @bahrep: yep. worked fine for me on my local Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Are you sure `f:\user\trac\myproject\VERSION` exists? this `VERSION` looks like a problem with unassigned environment variable

Comment: Are you 100% sure the software doesn't try to access `f:\\user\\trac\\myproject\\VERSION` (i.e. *with* the double slashes)? Windows doesn't compress duplicate path separators into one, so `C:\\Windows` isn't a valid path.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, you can add

```
import getpass
print >> sys.stderr, getpass.getuser()
```

right after the import statements for the hook, and it should output the username before the error when you try to push.

However, it's giving the error "No such file or directory" which likely means just that, it's trying to access a file which does not exist. So this would not be permissions issue, and could mean trac is not installed properly at that location or that there is a problem with the trac module.